# How to launch a perspective from a custom menu?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, menuitem, perspective

I'm new at programming and this is my first plugin... 
I designed a plugin with a menu and a perspective for my *.properties files. They work just fine.

Now, I would like to trigger the perspective once I click on a menu item(one of my menu's choices) which will trigger the opening of a *.properties file. Or perhaps, I shall rather open the perspective everytime I open a *.properties file ? I'm not sure which way is more appropriate.

How can I do that and where ? Should I do it in the Activator file (in the start method) or in the PerspectiveFactory file ?

Thank you for your kind help,

V

Comment: Don't do it in your Activator. That would be rude, and annoy users who want to use any other Perspective. What does your Perspective offer that makes it so useful?

Comment: Thanks. If I do it in the menu handler, how should I proceed? My solution doesn't work : I added a new PerspectiveListener to the execution method of the handler of my menu item. 
I hope my perspective will propose an editor of properties files to get outline of beans, syntax coloration  and even maybe some Drag n drop of beans. (to know more about the kind of files I will use see M. Fowler [link](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

Comment: A PerspectiveListener is notified about changes, it doesn't affect change. Your handler would make use of the org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil to obtain the active workbench window and tell it to open your Perspective using `openPage()`. It actually sounds like you want to provide an *editor* that contributes a page to the Outline view, among other features, rather than a whole perspective.

Comment: thanks for your precious help. it helps, the perspective now opens in a new window but not in the current. I guess it's another subject, I should work on.

Yes,  my perspective will include an editor and some views like you said. Actually, the exact behaviour is when I click on my menu I open a file in a new perspective environnement. My next step is to code the editor.

Comment: This subject is resolved. FYI, To open the perspective in the same window :  
`
IWorkbenchWindow activeWorkbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
  IWorkbenchPage workbenchPage = activeWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage();
  IPerspectiveRegistry perspRegistry = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry();
  IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective = perspRegistry.findPerspectiveWithId("SPL.perspective4");
  workbenchPage.setPerspective(perspective);
` thanks for your help.